# perforce: list history of a file in main depot

Tags: perforce, clearcase

I want to find out the history of a file in main depot. In `clearcase` I can do with the following command

```
% ct lshist -r -branch main -since "01-Jan-2014" hello.cpp
```

What is the equivalent command in `p4`? I tried `p4 filelog` but wasn't able to come up with the right args.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
p4 changes -l //depot/path/to/file
```

will display all changes to the file with the full description for each.

Comment: Just for the sake of completeness: for a single file you can also use "p4 filelog -l //depot/path/to/file". You will then additionally see filetype changes (if any), deletions and readds (if any) and integrations/merges (if any)

Comment: If you want to restrict the list to changes since a certain date (e.g. 01-Jan-2014), add revision specifiers: see 'p4 help revisions'.